# В результатах работы программы на Python не отображаются русские символы. Запускаю с помощью Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, pycharm

Пытаюсь разобраться с кодировками и написал программу, выдающую символы по их номеру. По-моему в диапазоне номеров 128-255 должны встретиться русские буквы, а их нет. Попробовал поменять настройки редактора, результата не дало. Что нужно сделать чтобы в результатах работы программы появились русские буквы?[image: скрин программы и результата]

[image: скрин настроек Pycharm]

Comment: "_По-моему в диапазоне номеров 128-255 должны встретиться русские буквы_" - не должны. Возьмите таблицу юникода и посмотрите, где там русские буквы.

Comment: Действительно, начинаются с 1040. Спасибо. @Эникейщик, сделайте комментарий ответом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Коды с 127 до 255 в UTF-8 совпадают с кодировкой ISO 8859 (вроде бы). Т.е. в основном разные спецбуквы латинского алфавита.

А русские буквы в UTF-8 имеют коды с 1040   (0x0410) до 1103 (0x044F).

А весь набор кириллические (куда входят не буквы не только русского алфавита, но и сербского, черногорского и т.д.) - с 1024 (0x0400) до 1279 (0x04FF).

Answer (score 0):

В данном диапазоне нет русских букв (╭ರ_⊙)

Comment: Да, я понял. Спасибо!